# Flex: Is it possible to pass multiple strings between views?

Tags: apache-flex, view

I have a list of text files and when one is selected it is read and assigned to a string variable. this string is then pushed to a view : pushView(viewer, string), where the string is displayed in a textarea. I want to also pass the relative path of the file also. Is this possible to pass two strings?

```
protected function view1_viewActivateHandler(event:ViewNavigatorEvent):void
            {
                if(data!=null){
                    mainTextField.text = data.toString();
                }else{
                    mainTextField.text = "";
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible.  Typically the way I do this in Flex is to add a `data` property on my view of type `Object` allowing me to pass any type of object into the view.

In your case I would change `pushView(viewer, string)` to something like `pushView(viewer, data)` where `data` is some object that stores all the data you need to pass to the view. `data` might look like:

```
var data:Object = { text: "my text to display", 
                    relativePath: "the/relative/path" };
```

Comment: It would be even better to create a separate class for that object e.g. `public class SomeData() { ... }` and pass it like `pushView(viewer, new SomeData("my text", "my path"))`

Comment: @Maxim Agreed. Thanks for adding that bit.

Comment: Thanks! How would I access the two values in my View_Handler? Please see edit for how I'm accessing the passed value now.

Comment: Got it. It was easier than I thought it would be, just data.text, and data.relativePath in my view_handler. Thanks again